# Uploading asp.net core 3.1 Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to upload files in ASP.NET core 3.1, but in my Post I'm not receiving the file.

That **count = 0** is what I always get.

@cshtml

```
 <input asp-for="app.FormFile" id="input-2" name="input2[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">
```

@cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size });
}
```

In ASP.NET core 2.0 this worked fine! What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The param name is `files`, but you're explicitly setting the input name to `input2[]`, so they don't match up. ASP.NET Core isn't going to try to interpret that you've uploaded some files so you probably want them to go on this param. If it can't find something to bind the data to (by name), it's just going to discard it and move on.

The name should `files` so it matches up to the param name: `name="files"`.

Answer (score 0):

> even if I pass the name it still came with count = 0 `<input asp-for="Laudos.FormFile" id="files" name="files" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">`

You can try to specify an encoding type (enctype) of `multipart/form-data` for your `<form>` tag, like below.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="Laudos.FormFile" id="input-2" name="files" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Test Result

[image]